# Node.js + express how to add string to the request url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

I have a reverse proxy that works great like this:

```
app.all('/geoserver', function (req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});
```

I need to add to the request url a string like this:

> &cql_filer=strSubstring(codigo,0,3)=%27201%27

Before proxying to the `serverOne`.

Tried with `req = req + '&cql_filer=strSubstring(codigo,0,3)=%27201%27';` but it is not working.

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `req` is an object. maybe you are looking for `req.url`

Comment: seems you want to add the query parameters, better append the same rather url. i.e. `req.query = {...req.query, cql_filer: <your data>}`

Comment: You are right. Please post it as answer for marking as solution @JonasWilms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy module seems to use `req.url` to determine the url to proxy to. You can change `req.url` to your needs.